# Vertical align content within two divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have two divs next to each other.
The left div contains a logo and the right div contains one line of links(menu)

I want to vertical align the menu in the right div to the logo in the left div.
This is the code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="logo">
        image.jpg
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
    link 1  | link 2 | link 3
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#header{
padding: 3% 0 2% 0;
width: 100%;
display:table;
}

.logo{
display:inline-block;
max-width:19%;  
text-align:left;
}

.navigation{
display:inline-block;
text-align:right;
width:81%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you want:

```css
#header {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 3% 0 2% 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 19%;
  text-align: left;
}

.navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 81%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div class="logo">
        image.jpg
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
    link 1  | link 2 | link 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this did work but what the hell are all the display options...? Time to read up! Thnx

Answer (score 2):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) should do the trick. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/566s4ext/).

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
}

.navigation {
    flex: 0 0 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace inline-block with table-cell. It will work.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to the CSS flexbox solutions...

https://jsfiddle.net/bLmcpc15/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img id="logoimg" src="http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png">
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
    link 1  | link 2 | link 3
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imgHeight = $("#logoimg").height();
    var navHeight = $("#navigation").height();
    var topMargin = (imgHeight-navHeight)/2;
    $("#navigation").css({"margin-top":topMargin});
});
```